# «Можешь, пожалуйста...» — так можно говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этикет

*Можешь мне, пожалуйста, подсказать телефон Оли Палеолог, любовницы моего мужа?

Кирюша, любимый, можешь, пожалуйста, сделать мне ребёночка?

Можешь, пожалуйста, дверь закрыть?

Можешь, пожалуйста, передать Алисе цветы от Нонны?

Можете, пожалуйста, назначить меня заместителем директора по воспитательной работе?*

И т. п.

«Можешь, пожалуйста...» — так можно говорить?

Answer (score 5):

Так говорить не должно, и для образованных людей старшего поколения этот оборот звучит непривычно. Однако язык эволюционирует, и мне уже приходилось слышать этот оборот от молодых, притом относительно образованных, людей. Пока неясно, приживётся ли он в языке (надеюсь, что нет). Его вероятным истоком являются английские конструкции типа "may I please..." и "could you please".

Answer (score 5):

Мне тоже такие обороты не нравятся, кажутся грамматически неверными, излишними. "Пожалуйста" отлично сочетается с глаголами в повелительном наклонении. Просто и вежливо:
*Закрой, пожалуйста, дверь; Пожалуйста, закрой дверь;

Передай, пожалуйста;

Объясните, пожалуйста.*

> [**Вопрос № 309848**](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309848)
>
> Допустимы ли фразы вроде "Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить подробнее?" или "Не передадите ли, будьте добры, деньги?"?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> В разговорной речи подобные конструкции не редкость. Однако литературной нормой они пока не стали, и рекомендовать их к употреблению нельзя. О конструкции *Можно, пожалуйста...* подробно рассказала О. И. Северская в статье «[Можно, пожалуйста, чувствовать себя новой?](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/3881377)».

**Из этой статьи:**

> Современное *можно, пожалуйста*,— это, конечно, калька с англоязычной конструкции May I please «Могу ли я/могу я?..», которая поначалу переводилась на русский «как положено»: **May I please** have a glass of water? «**Можно** мне стакан воды?»; Dad, **may I please** have the potatoes? «Пап, **пожалуйста**, передай мне картошку»; а теперь перевод соответствует «тренду»: **May I please** inspect the bathroom? «**Могу я, пожалуйста**, осмотреть ванную?» (хотя и здесь вполне возможны были бы «нормальные» русские формы *а можно мне?.. могу ли я?..*).
> <...>
> «Ванильное», нежно-пастельное, как положено, романтичное, необычное и с глубоким смыслом «*можно, пожалуйста*» хоть и появилось не так давно, но уже настолько распространилось в молодежной среде, что попытки это как-то скорректировать напоминают борьбу Дон Кихота с ветряными мельницами.

Answer (score 3):

Странный оборот, впервые услышал его от своей ассистентки, которая меня младше на 10 лет. Действительно, так говорит, в основном, молодежь, и звучит это несколько непривычно. Думаю, в литературной речи такой оборот употреблять нельзя, а в разговорной, похоже, это стало нормой.

Answer (score 2):

По-русски говорят: "не могли бы вы, то и то-то, пожалуйста." "Можешь" и "пожалуйста" звучит как тавтология, потому что можешь - это позволение другому, причем с позиции начальника, главного, а пожалуйста - просьба нижестоящего, подчиненного, поэтому возникает семантическая путаница соц ролей и звучит слащаво, и, вероятно,  так можно сказать, если фраза несёт саркастический оттенок. В русском языке "мочь" связано с "Я", то есть разрешить себе "мочь" что-то человек должен сам, а не с позволения другого. Поэтому задается вопрос "не мог бы ты..?", на что человек отвечает: "могу, конечно."

А вот в английском отношение к "Я" другое, поэтому там говорят "ты можешь" - "я позволяю тебе/тебе позволено", в то время как "плиз" значит - "тебе будет это приятно", "плизд ми" - это что-то вроде "порадуй меня", "потешь меня". В то время как "пожалуйте" - значит, приглашение войти, начать что-то, а если еще точнее "пожалуйте" - проявите жалость, отсюда и нотка позиции более низкого по статусу использующего данное вежливое слово. Калька получается при переводе неравнозначных по семантике лексем, то есть по-английски "пожалуйста" это скорее "to have a mercy", то есть что-то вроде прояви милость, "будь милостив (посетить мой дом)" - хотя тоже не совсем то, потому что сжалься и будь милостив тоже не совсем одно и тоже. Но в английском в принципе не свойственно отношение к гостю как к временному "господину" в твоем доме - дорогому гостю, как это принято на востоке.

То есть еще корректнее, если делать аналогичную кальку при переводе на английский, то пожалуйста нужно было бы переводить как "be pity" - испытайте жалость, вы можете). *Вы не могли бы, пожалуйста* => *You couldn't* (в утвердительном смысле! что в английском в принципе бред) *to don't may self*(придётся добавить второе отрицание, потому что минус на минус, наверное, даст плюс), *be pity to me*.