# Современное употребление "можно"

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл

> *А можно повторить вопрос?*

Разве так нормально говорить? Суть в том, что подразумевается **"можете",** в то время как "можно" обычно относится **к самому себе:**

*А можно мне тоже кусочек?

Можно сказать?*

Comment: А вот такие вопросы правильны или нет?https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476742/Можно-ли-использовать-несколько-предложений-во-вставках-с-тире   Голос от меня.

Comment: А вы про какие спрашиваете? Если про вопрос в заголовке, то вроде с ним всё в порядке. Спасибо за голос!)

Comment: Я обращала внимание, что мне тоже не нравится слово "можно" в вопросах (в заголовке или в тексте – без разницы). Как будто у нас разрешение спрашивают.

Comment: Именно! Рад, что вы разделяете мои чувства. ;)

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что можно адресовано кому-то? Можно - это не позволяю, позвольте, позволю.

Comment: Можно не адресовано, оно про себя или про нас.

Comment: С чего вы так решили?

Comment: Ну знаю, не первый год живу.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/469767/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%88%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c

Answer (score 4):

***А можно** повторить вопрос?*

1. В такой форме употребление слова "можно" представляется мне корректным. Значение такое: **есть ли возможность для повтора вопроса.** Дело не в чьем-то разрешении, здесь скорее речь идет  о технических или организационных **возможностях.**
2. Такое значение есть **в словаре:**

Большой толковый словарь

**МОЖНО,** в функц. безл. сказ. с инф. 1. **О возможности для осуществления чего-л.;** есть условия для совершения какого-л. действия. Сегодня м. кататься на лыжах. М. пойти в лес. На солнце м. загорать. 2. **кому-чему и с инф. Разрешается, позволительно.** М. войти. М. выключить телевизор. Есть ещё желающие? — М. мне? К вам м.? — Пожалуйста, присаживайтесь.

Выбираем **первое** значение (о возможности для осуществления чего-л.).

Другими словами, в словаре есть **подтверждение**: можно повторить — это "есть ли **возможность** для повтора вопроса"?

Comment: Вы же написали, что замечали, что вам это тоже не нравится, а теперь полностью оправдывается это.

Comment: Артем, обратите внимание: у слова два значения: возможность (1) и разрешение (2). Я говорила о разрешении (2) в заданных на форуме вопросах, это мне не нравится. А в вашем случае это возможность (1).

Comment: Ладно, плюсик вам в любом случае, спасибо! Но я надеялся на что-то другое...

Comment: Спасибо!  Мне тоже хочется услышать другие мнения. Признаться, я считала этот вариант разговорным упрощением словосочетания "есть ли возможность для повтора вопроса". Но из словаря вижу, что это значение закреплено в словаре.

Comment: Можно ли вам посмотреть и мой новый ответ?) я старался)

Comment: Честно говоря, я его уже видела. И честно говоря, он мне очень понравился.  На месте Артема я приняла бы ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Новый ответ.

[Можно используется в вопросах очень часто](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CqgCEoMCCoACChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluChcKB2Rpc3Rtb2QSDAoKd2l0aF96ZXJvcxJbChMKA2xleBIMCgrQvNC%2B0LbQvdC%2BCgoKBGZvcm0SAgoACgsKBWdyYW1tEgIKAAoJCgNzZW0SAgoAChUKB3NlbS1tb2QSCgoIc2VtfHNlbXgKCQoDc3luEgIKABJzCgkKA2xleBICCgAKCgoEZm9ybRICCgAKCwoFZ3JhbW0SAgoACgkKA3NlbRICCgAKFQoHc2VtLW1vZBIKCghzZW18c2VteAoJCgNzeW4SAgoAChIKBWZsYWdzEgkKByhicXVlcykKDAoEZGlzdCIECAEQMioZCgkI%2BQgQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQEwAQ==), но чаще в риторических фигурах или сложных вопросах, с прибавкой "ли" в значении "позволено ли". В виде вежливой просьбы обращение с "можно" чаще выглядело как "не можно ли"/"нельзя ли". То есть, данные вопросительные формулировки ни что иное, как сокращение от "можно или нельзя".

> Господин доктор, **не можно ли** этого до завтра отложить?  А. П. Сумароков. Приданое обманом (1769)

> Я видь говорил, что хвост только свой видишь, а головы не знаешь. Так **можно ли** узнать человека из одной его пяты?  Григорий Сковорода. Наркисс (1760-1769)

> Вопр. **Можно ли** хотя несколько Бога описать? Отв. Можно; да только описаниями очень не собственными, то есть, не такими, которыя бы нам точно Его представили, но темными, и сколько понятию нашему вместительно. Вопр. Какое же бы то было о Боге понятие?  архиепископ Платон (Левшин). Катихизис десятый (1758)

> Фатюй. **Можно ли и** мне туды войти? Салмина. А. П. Сумароков. Ссора у мужа с женой (1750)

> § 23. Вопрос 3. **Не можно ли** костей оных причесть к числу во время создания от создателя в земле произведенных? Ответ. Сему подобное мнение случилось мне читать, якобы бог при сотворении мира учиня многие тела, ис которых потребное число оживотворил, а протчие оставил брошены. И на оное ответ, или паче опровержение, Бутнер в книге своей Остатки разорения потопного довольно изобразил. Татищев.

> Я спрашиваю у ней, **нельзя ли** гдѣ купить здѣсь вишенъ? А. С. Шишков. Записки (1780-1814)

Бытовой вопрос с можно:

> — «В зале присутствия». — «**Можно** его видеть?». — «Спросите у курьера». 11459. С. П. Жихарев. Записки современника (1806-1809)

**Постановка "А" вначале фразы** сходное "НУ, МММ, ЭЭЭ" называется ["речевое колебание"](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/198980636) - речевые паузы, когда человек неуверен, не может или не решается спросить утвердительно:

> Термином «хезитация» принято обозначать «речевое колебание» (Гуманитарный словарь 2002) или «внутренний перебив в процессе речепорождения, связанный с тем, что говорящий в силу каких-либо причин оказывается не способным продолжать говорение» (Яковлев 1998: 176 — цит. по Метлова 2012).

[Вопросы с "а можно?"](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=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):

> — **А можно** ему у вас пробыть нынче денек? — сказал старик с такой **робкой улыбкой**... Толстой.

> «Странно!» — подумал Лугин. — **А можно посмотреть номер?** Дворник **опять пристально взглянул** на него. — Как нельзя? — можно! — отвечал он и пошел переваливаясь за ключами. Лермонтов.

Как видно, формулировка "а можно?" отражает сосредоточенное или неуверенное состояние спрашивающего, и подобную специфику речи можно использовать как литературный штрих.

Хотя, в некоторых случаях "а можно", если это не просьба, может иметь вложенное значение "нельзя":

> Жадов. Дитя! Останьтесь всегда таким ребенком. Полина. **А можно** счесть звезды на небе? Жадов. Можно. Полина. **Нет, нельзя.** А. Н. Островский. Доходное место (1857)

Однако, говорить так вполне можно, это вполне классическая форма языка!